# How does web-container handles incoming request and maps to a deployed web-application war

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-container

I want to understand how the web-container maps incoming requests to a particular web-application (and a servlet afterwards).

To begin with, I believe a web-container must be able to listen for incoming Http requests (else how will the client reach to web-application at all). This assumption I believe holds correct. If this is not correct, then how does request will ever reach to web-container?

Now, assume I wrote a web-application (based on plain servlets i.e., not using any other framework like Spring MVC), create the .war file, say `firstwebapp.war`; and deployed it in Apache Tomcat, with context root `/firstapp`

Now, the client makes request to the deployed web-application as:

```
http://servername:port/firstapp
```

How does the web-container handle this request? Where is this mapping of /firstapp to the web-application deployed as `firstwebapp.war`?

Does web-container first "sees" the incoming request URL before passing on the control to respective web-application? And based on what criteria is it able to map to proper .war?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the server will see `/firstapp` first and know where to rout it. After that it depends on your war, e.g., your `web.xml`.

Comment: But where is this mapping defined? I know at the time of deployment, in tomcat we specify /contex_root to a particular .war? Is this information stored somewhere in tomcat?